# Most memory efficient way to split an NSString in to substrings

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have the following code:

```
    int start = [html rangeOfString:@"class=WordSection1>"].location + 24;
    int end = [html rangeOfString:@"<div class=\"endofsections\">"].location;
    self.parts = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    NSString* startHtml = [html substringToIndex:start - 1];
    NSString* mainHtml = [html substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(start - 1, end - start - 1)];
    NSString* endHtml = [html substringFromIndex:end];
    // !! At this point we have the string in memory twice
    [html release];

    [self.parts addObject: startHtml];

    NSArray *splitHtml = [mainHtml componentsSeparatedByString:@"<p class=NumberedParagraph>"];
    //[mainHtml release]; <-- this causes bad access errors. Does the split do a copy or does it just create a new set of pointers but use the same memory?

    for(NSString* part in splitHtml){
        if (first){
            [self.parts addObject: part];
            first = NO;
        } else {
            [self.parts addObject: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<p class=NumberedParagraph>%@", part]];
        }
     }

    [self.parts addObject:endHtml];
```

The issue with this is that html is about 20Mb. I split it in to startHtml, mainHtml and endHtml. After splitting it I then release html. However prior to this release all 4 NSStrings are in memory so the app is using an extra 40Mb or so.

I then split mainHtml and assign the substrings to an NSArray called splitHtml, this again means that they are stored in memory twice. I try to release mainHtml but this causes an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error.

Is there any way to get around this object being stored in memory twice before being released issue?

I plan to replace the for loop with a while loop that removes the processed NSStrings from splitHtml. The loop condition will be satisfied when splitHtml is empty. This is so that as the parts array consumes more memory the splitHtml array consumes less memory. Do I need to release each NSString or can I just remove it and have the array consume less memory as a whole?

Thanks,

Joe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well.. you can't release mainHtml because it is created as an autorelease object, so release will get called after your function is done and it will crash if the object is already released by then.

You could try to create an extra function that splits the string and returns the array, perhaps with an own autorelease pool that you release after the function is run to make sure the strings are released.

Comment: Ah thanks. I now do a retain and release like this: 
 `        NSString* mainHtml = [[html substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(start - 1, end - start - 1)] retain];
        NSArray *splitHtml = [mainHtml componentsSeparatedByString:@"<p class=NumberedParagraph>"];
        [mainHtml release];` 
 
Is this the correct way of doing it? This seems to crash Instruments for some reason so I can't see the actual memory usage.

Answer (score 2):

Parsing HTML using `rangeOfString:`, `NSScanner` or regular expressions is futile.  It might work for your test case, but it is going to break as soon as the HTML changes.

I.e. keep in mind that:

```
<div class=\"endofsections\">
```

And:

```
<div    class=\"endofsections\"   id=1 
    title="End Of Sections"  >
```

Are both identical in terms of the `class` attribute.

Use a proper HTML parser.

Comment: Yes normally people can get away with writing all sorts of crazy HTML but this HTML is a word document that has been saved as HTML by our client. Word has its own proprietry schema and outputs HTML in a pretty standard way. The HTML might change every year or two but when it does we will be aware of it and will push a new release. *edit endofsections isn't something that you normally find in an HTML document saved by word - I added that myself.

Comment: "following standards" in HTML does not require either stable whitespace output nor that the key=value pairs in tags be preserved at all.  If you build a parser that is dependent on either, it will break.

Comment: I have to agree with @bbum here. Using a real HTML parser will save you headaches down the line.

Comment: Yes but the HTML isn't going to change. If it ever does happen to change then I'm going to have to modify it a lot anyway. The endofsections div is something that I add myself. I'll just not use any funny spacing etc if I have to add it again.

Comment: Mmm.... yeah.  "The HTML will never change".  I've heard that before.   :)  The point is that the HTML *can* change without actually changing meaning.