# Trying to split a very large string

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsstring

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Most memory efficient way to split an NSString in to substrings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7390226/most-memory-efficient-way-to-split-an-nsstring-in-to-substrings)

I'm trying to split a 20Mb string. I've tried using componentsSeparatedByString but it consumes too much RAM. I think that this is down to the fact that it splits the string but also leaves the original string intact. This means that the string is effectivly stored in memory twice (even if I release the original string right after the split it is still an issue.)

I'm very new to Objective C. I've tried to write some code that removes the substring from the original string as it adds it to the array of found strings. The idea is that as the mutable array of found strings gets larger the original string gets smaller. The only problem is that it leaks memory and crashes. If someone could tell me what I'm doing wrong then that yould be great!

```
    NSRange range = [mainHtml rangeOfString:@"<p class=NumberedParagraph>"];
    int counter = 1;

    // locations will == int max if it can't find any more occurances
    while (range.location < [mainHtml length]) {
        NSString *curStr;
        NSRange curStrRange;

        NSRange rangeToSearchIn = NSMakeRange(range.location+1, [mainHtml length] - range.location - 1);
        NSRange nextRange = [mainHtml rangeOfString:@"<p class=NumberedParagraph>" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:rangeToSearchIn];

        if (nextRange.location > [mainHtml length])
        {
            // This is the last string - get everything up to the end of the file
            curStrRange = NSMakeRange(0, [mainHtml length]);
            curStr = [mainHtml substringFromIndex:range.location];
        } else {
            curStrRange = NSMakeRange(range.location, nextRange.location - range.location);
            curStr = [mainHtml substringWithRange:curStrRange];
        }

        // Remove the substring just processed from the orignal string
        // * it crashes here, normally on the 3rd itteration
        mainHtml = [mainHtml substringFromIndex:curStrRange.location + curStrRange.length];
        range = [mainHtml rangeOfString:@"<p class=NumberedParagraph>"];

        [self.parts addObject:curStr];
    }
```

Comment: `if (nextRange.location > [mainHtml length])` I don't think that's right, shouldn't it be `>=`?

Comment: I'm not certain about Objective C but I know that in other languages (C#) indexes are 0 based whilst lengths aren't so the last character would be at length - 1. I'll find out though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that @babbidi had the correct idea. mainHtml is large and you have many autoreleased copies of it around (one copy for each iteration) that are not being released. Try adding the following @autorelease in your code to release all the autoreleased objects at the end of each loop. If you are not using Mac OS X 10.7 then you need only create the autorelease pool manually outside the main loop and drain it once per iteration.

```
NSRange range = [mainHtml rangeOfString:@"<p class=NumberedParagraph>"];
int counter = 1;

// locations will == int max if it can't find any more occurances
while (range.location < [mainHtml length]) {
    @autorelease {
        NSString *curStr;
        NSRange curStrRange;

        NSRange rangeToSearchIn = NSMakeRange(range.location+1, [mainHtml length] - range.location - 1);
        NSRange nextRange = [mainHtml rangeOfString:@"<p class=NumberedParagraph>" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:rangeToSearchIn];

        if (nextRange.location > [mainHtml length])
        {
            // This is the last string - get everything up to the end of the file
            curStrRange = NSMakeRange(0, [mainHtml length]);
            curStr = [mainHtml substringFromIndex:range.location];
        } else {
            curStrRange = NSMakeRange(range.location, nextRange.location - range.location);
            curStr = [mainHtml substringWithRange:curStrRange];
        }

        // Remove the substring just processed from the orignal string
        // * it crashes here, normally on the 3rd itteration
        mainHtml = [mainHtml substringFromIndex:curStrRange.location + curStrRange.length];
        range = [mainHtml rangeOfString:@"<p class=NumberedParagraph>"];

        [self.parts addObject:curStr];
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 if creating lots of small autoreleased objects, use an autorelease pool!

Comment: An autorelease pool fixed it! The one problem is that it is now really slow. In a comment against babbidi's answer I linked to some C code which also didn't leak but was very slow. Is this just because I'm moving 20mb of data around when I assign newHtmlString and then assign that to the now released htmlString? Is there anything that I can do about this? Thanks, Joe.

Comment: @user940516 There is something that you could do that would not require the autorelease pool and would improve performance considerably. Don't copy mainHtml. Instead build an array of ranges using NSValue and if you need the substrings only at the end should you build this array using your ranges array. This should require at most ~40 MB of memory (give or take a little overhead).

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you have any leaks. `substringFromIndex:` returns an autoreleased string, so it might be kept in memory for more then one iteration. You could create your own `substringFromIndex:`  method (e.g: `createSubstringFromIndex`) which will return a string retained string which you can manually release.

```
+(NSString *)createSubstringFromIndex:(NSUInteger)index string:(NSString *)string{
    int newLen = [string length] - index;
    if(newLen<=0)
        return @"";   // or nil
    char *cStr = malloc(newLen+1);
    for(int i=index; i<[string length]; i++){
        cStr[i-index]=[string characterAtIndex:i];
    }
    cStr[newLen]='\0';
    NSString *retStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithCString:cStr encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    free(cStr);
    return retStr;
}
```

in your code you'd have to replace this:

```
mainHtml = [mainHtml substringFromIndex:curStrRange.location + curStrRange.length];
```

with this:

```
NSString *newHtmlString = [[self class] createSubstringFromIndex:curStrRange.location + curStrRange.length string:mainHtml];
[mainHtml release];                ///mainHtml should be retained before the while loop starts
mainHtml = newHtmlString;
```

Comment: Thanks. You are the first person on here to actually provide me with code to fix an issue instead of some abstract "you could kind of do something a bit like this..." idea which I then have to attempt to write code for.

Comment: Ah, it doesn't work though. It uses more and more RAM and then crashes on this line: NSString *retStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithCString:cStr encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

Comment: are you releasing `mainHtml` inside the loop?

Comment: Yes. I can't see why it isn't working.

Comment: can you provide a large sample of `mainHtml`?

Comment: I'm not sure if I am allowed but I can find out. I've tried doing it in mostly plain C. It doesn't leak anymore but it's stupidly slow (I've not seen it finish since it has to process about 4500 substrings and is doing one every second or so. Here is the code if your interested: http://pastebin.com/sEDnb0Hb